# Need to boot partitions for Windows and Xubuntu from BIOS - GRUB doesn't work

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I run Xubuntu (I think it's 18.04) in legacy mode alongside Windows 10 (I assume in UEFI mode), with no bootloader (grub) option. I have to boot the respective partitions from the bios (win - drive c: or linux - drive d:). Also I have exclamation marks in the EFI partitions of both drives showing up in gparted. So what can I do here to get something like a grub bootloader working? Can I use this command in Windows to activate?

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

Also, can I disable hibernation in Windows without risk?

Thanks for your reply and your ongoing efforts in supporting linux rookies ;)